# How to set hostname in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am using the following code to generate screenshot of our internal page. Here you can see that i am using IP address instead of host name. since we are using name based virtual hosting, without proper host name our web server wont respond with proper page. Can we set the hostname/domain name(www.example.com) in this code     .

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://170.90.23.27/TEST/')
browser.save_screenshot('screenie.png')
browser.quit()
display.stop()
```

Comment: Any problem with string concatenation for composing the complete URL?

Comment: this urls are Apache reverse proxy urls, that is the reason why we are using IP, and passing host header.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: You I've trying to put the domain ? The get() method make you navigate to a page with a given url, after the page has loaded you can make any operations that you want.
       Try to configure the proxy on Firefox:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *


myProxy = "host:8080"

proxy = Proxy({
   'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
   'httpProxy': myProxy,
   'ftpProxy': myProxy,
   'sslProxy': myProxy,
   'noProxy': '' # set this value as desired
})

driver = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=proxy)

driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

Docs:

- http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html
- http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy

Comment: This above script is working fine but i am getting 404 not found because i am not passing the host header.

Comment: Can some one help me on this?

Comment: This is completely different this code to support web proxy. I am not looking for  this , i am looking for code to support passing Host